# is there a numpy function that equivalent to python map

Tags: python, numpy

i have a 3d array that contains n 2d arrays
is there anyway that i can map each 2d array to some value
with out using the bulit in python map or for loops (i have been asked to do with out it)
only with numpy functions.

for example i want to do something like that:

```
def map2d_arr(arr2d): #this is for the exampe only can be any condition on the 2d array
    return sum(arr2d) > 10;

a = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
res = np.map(map2d_arr,a) # how to do something like that only in numpy
                          #should return boolean array
```

there is np.vectorize and along axis
but they dont take full 2d arrays

Comment: just use `res = sum(a) > 10` numpy returns a list of `Boolean` for you

Answer (score 0):

**No,** but you can easily make a lambda function to serve that purpose.

```
list = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

#define function
my_function = lambda x: x*2

#apply function to NumPy array
my_function(list)

#Result : list = [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: tnx but this is not helping, because  your solution take scalars only i need to check condition on 2d matrices inside a 3d matrix

Answer (score 0):

Let's drop the boolean test, and just use `sum` - it clarifies the dimensional action:

```
In [130]: a = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
```

You apparently want to apply `sum` to each of the 2d arrays, iterating on the first dimension.

```
In [131]: sum(a[0])
Out[131]: array([ 9, 12, 15])
```

Effectively `a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2]`.

For this the python map works just fine:

```
In [132]: list(map(sum, a))
Out[132]: [array([ 9, 12, 15]), array([36, 39, 42]), array([63, 66, 69])]
```

Equivalently in list comprehension form:

```
In [133]: [sum(i) for i in a]
Out[133]: [array([ 9, 12, 15]), array([36, 39, 42]), array([63, 66, 69])]
```

Or using `vectorize` with `signature`:

```
In [134]: f = np.vectorize(sum, signature='(n,m)->(m)')
In [135]: f(a)
Out[135]: 
array([[ 9, 12, 15],
       [36, 39, 42],
       [63, 66, 69]])
```

but we can do the same with `np.sum`:

```
In [136]: np.sum(a, axis=1)
Out[136]: 
array([[ 9, 12, 15],
       [36, 39, 42],
       [63, 66, 69]])
```

[136] is, by far the fastest.  `vectorize` is slower than list comprehension for small cases, but scales better. `vectorize` with `signature` is generally slower (but that needs to be tested).  `map` and list comprehension are about the same.

`apply_along_axis` is generally slower, though it can simplify nested iterations.  I don't recommend it for 2d cases, where list comprehension is clean enough and faster.